# K-Nearest Neighbor in Image Recognition

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-recognition, knn

I am currently researching for projects or guide/tutorial for my research. I have to determine three leaf different species and is using 100 samples for each(300 just to be specific), my professor requires me to imply the K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm in classifying the uploaded image in the system using the 100 samples uploaded in the database as a reference.

I have done the uploading of the samples and image processing for the system, but I still have to apply the KNN algorithm in classifying them, any suggestions or step-by-step tutorials?

Is there a need to study in coding the algorithm or are there existing libraries for easily applying **KNN in image classifying in C# language**? and is having 100 image samples for each leaf specie enough?

more info.: a reply from martijin_himself's answer

Yes, I am talking about tree leaves. Well, a problem is, the only feature to consider is a tree leaf's shape. Neglecting other features such as color, size,..etc. And I don't exactly know when or how to extract these "Feature Vectors", where to put them and how the image samples will be used as a reference for the leaf to be classified

About the image processing part of the system, the image undergoes the process of binarization, and blobbing, having the image only consider it's shape only feature. So, same goes with all the samples I uploaded in the database. I am very sorry if I lack the information/s needed for the answers. Please bear with me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the question to answer it.  Can you tell us more about the image processing part of the system?

Comment: The KNN is subtle and the provided info is scarce. You should start reading Wikipedia and googling for a while. Then come up with a more focused question.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy - I had already added the info. in the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: @belisarius - Yes, indeed I am struggling in my research about KNN and I still don't have any idea on how to implement it in the system. There are several notes on KNN that I have seen/read, but most of them only refer to data mining and analyzing. None much about the programming or **Image/Pattern Recognition** process.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you have a training set of 300 images, 100 for each class (or label).

First, you have to define your feature vector, which is a set of image characteristics or attributes you think are important in classifying the images. If you are talking about (tree) leaves, one characteristic may be colour values in the image?

The second step would be to define a distance function that calculates the distance between feature vectors. An image with a lot of red would have a bigger distance to an image with a lot of green, for example. You could even weigh the features to reflect their importance in contribution to the distance.

Next, you can choose your value of k, and test how well the combination of your feature vector and distance function performs to classify the images with known labels for your training set. This is called cross-validation. If your feature vector and distance function does not perform well, you may have chosen attributes which are not representative for the class (such as size of the image).

When implementing this in c#, you could create a FeatureVector class for each image or something like that, and maybe implement the IComparable (or similar) interface to calculate the distance function to some known sample. You can then simply create a List and sort it. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I talking about tree leaves well, a problem is, the only feature to consider is a tree leaf's shape. Neglecting other features such as color, size,..etc. And I don't exactly know when or how to extract these "Feature Vectors", where to put them and how the image samples will be used as a reference for the leaf to be classified.

Comment: reference images from the database. what will they look like.

Comment: @user610075 As an example **sometimes** the ratio perimeter/area is used to get shapes appart. There are many others, of course.

Comment: @belisarius Then would it be sufficient if I used "Area-Based Pixel Matching" rather than KNN? Just a question I'm very curious, and maybe I can tell my professor about this, which would you prefer when it comes to accuracy of result/s?

Comment: @user610075 Each dataset is a world. How should I know in advance? Do some experiments. A software like Mathematica lets you prototype quickly.

Comment: @user610075 Does the exercise require you to use kNN? If "Area-Based Pixel Matching" gives you some kind of value representing similarity between one image and another, you have just found a feature for your feature vector, and you can use kNN.

Comment: @martijin_himself Thank you! This time I would be adding a column for the images in the database to refer to each images' area (rather the white/black pixels after binarization. And then use KNN to find what actually is the nearest among all the samples and compare them to the uploaded image in the system for the system to analyze. Please correct me if im wrong. And in this way, I can apply KNN in my study, thanks a lot @martijin_himself :)

Comment: @belisarius The idea for the Area-Based Matching was awesome, thanks a lot sir! :)

Comment: @user610075 Post some preliminary  results on your question (or in an answer) when you have them available. Good Luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I divided the image into two segments (top and bottom). But I had three feature vectors (Area of the leaf, area of it's top, and the area of it's bottom). Same with all the samples in the database.

So considering the three feature vectors that I have, I managed to apply the K-NN algorithm to my research by computing their distance/s (eauclidean, w/c is included in the K-NN algorithm) and classify them based on the user-defined value of K. So, the result had it in percentage.

Thanks for the help guys ^_^